# showing and removing a file name from a custom file input

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have this working fine to a point.
If you select a file then the file name shows correctly.

The problem comes when you remove the file the input shows nothing.

for example:
once you click the input and select a file, then click the input again and choose cancel. The field displays nothing.

```js
$('label.file').click(function() {
  $('.wpcf7-file').change(function() {
    var fileinput = jQuery('label.file').find('span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap');
    var filename = jQuery(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    $('label.file').html('<div class="input-value">' + filename + '</div>');
    $('label.file').prepend(fileinput);
  });
})
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.file {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  color: #888;
  background: #fff;
  width: calc(95% - 6px);
  font-family: Open Sans;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.input-value {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
<label class="file">Choose a file...
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-70">
<input name="file-70" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" type="file">
</span>
</label>
</span>
```

Comment: firefox shows the previous selected file. which browser are you testing on?

Comment: The issue is on google chrome, works fine on firefox.

Comment: @julekgwa sorry I should have added the browser I was experiencing the issue on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `filename` is empty or not.

```js
$('label.file').click(function() {
  $('.wpcf7-file').change(function() {
    var fileinput = jQuery('label.file').find('span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap');
    var filename = jQuery(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    if(filename !='')
    $('label.file').html('<div class="input-value">' + filename + '</div>');
    $('label.file').prepend(fileinput);
  });
})
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.file {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  color: #888;
  background: #fff;
  width: calc(95% - 6px);
  font-family: Open Sans;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px grey;
}

.input-value {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
<label class="file">Choose a file...
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap file-70">
<input name="file-70" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" aria-invalid="false" type="file">
</span>
</label>
</span>
```